# How to consume click event in view hierarchy

Tags: android

Is there a way to consume click events on a view so that it does not propagate to any other view in the view hierarchy?

For example, i have a view hierarchy that looks something like this :

```
List View -> LinearLayout(List view item) -> TableRow -> Space
```

I would like to consume the click event on the Space widget so that it does not propagate to the list view item.

Comment: Are you using Fragments?

Comment: @TiagoBarreto yes, that should not make any difference to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

return true from the onTouchEvent handler.  Also, needs to set the Space widget's visibility to VISIBLE by

```
space.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Not sure if this is a bug in the widget's code or by design not to respond to touch events.

Comment: onClick has a void return type

Comment: try to register an onclick listener for space setOnClickListener in onCreate, and then return true from it.

Comment: how does one return a boolean in a method that returns void?

Comment: sorry, onTouchEvent, not onClick.

Comment: the onTouchListener does not get called at all on the space widget. not sure why. It does work on other widgets.

Comment: Check the dimensions of the space, maybe it's really small or something.

Comment: if i replace the space with a button of the exact same dimension, it works. Increasing the dimensions made no difference to the behaviour with the space widget. Weird.

Comment: I notice that Space sets the visibility to INVISIBLE, try to set the widgets visibility to VISIBLE by .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) in onCreate, does it make a difference?

Comment: OMG that worked! thank you. Where did you find that the visibility is set for Space? ok nevermind..found it at http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/Space.java#36

Comment: It's in the source code, could be a bug?  Don't know for sure what the intention of it was to do that.